# how use flutter for routing dynamic deep link in website(crm)?

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation

how navigate directly to custom dynamic url in flutter web ?
for example this is the url : https://example.com/panel/account/site?accountId=**16501**&siteId=**5103**
how navigate to this url directly and get params from url?

Comment: You can use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/qlevar_router) to help you with that. See this example https://qlevar-router.netlify.app/#/params?test=480&go=586

Comment: anyone used fluro package? does it work for direct dynamic routing as i asked above?
https://pub.dev/packages/fluro
and this is a tutorial for this package:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVJiZlYZfWw&t=648s